# PyTorch: why is the loss unchanging, in this simple example?

Tags: pytorch, mathematical-optimization, torch

I'm writing a code example to do a simple linear projection (like PCA) in PyTorch. Everything appears to be OK except that the **loss does not change** as training progresses. Changing the learning rate doesn't affect this, and it's a simple one-dimensional problem so the loss should certainly be changing. What am I missing here?

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as nnF


class PCArot2D(nn.Module):
    "2D PCA rotation, expressed as a gradient-descent problem"
    def __init__(self):
        super(PCArot2D, self).__init__()
        self.theta = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(np.random.random() * 2 * np.pi))

    def getrotation(self):
        sintheta = torch.sin(self.theta)
        costheta = torch.cos(self.theta)
        return torch.tensor([[costheta, -sintheta], [sintheta, costheta]], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.double)

    def forward(self, x):
        xmeans = torch.mean(x, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        rot = self.getrotation()

        return torch.mm(rot, x - xmeans)

def covariance(y):
    "Calculates the covariance matrix of its input (as torch variables)"
    ymeans = torch.mean(y, dim=1, keepdim=True)
    ycentred = y - ymeans
    return torch.mm(ycentred, ycentred.T) / ycentred.shape[1]


net = PCArot2D()

example2 = torch.tensor(np.random.randn(2, 33))


# define a loss function and an optimiser
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.1)

# train the network
num_epochs = 1000
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # forward + backward + optimize
    outputs = net(torch.DoubleTensor(example2))
    # the covariance between output channels is the measure that we wish to minimise
    covariance = (outputs[0, :] * outputs[1, :]).mean()
    loss = criterion(covariance, torch.tensor(0, dtype=torch.double))

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    running_loss = loss.item()
    if ((epoch & (epoch - 1)) == 0) or epoch==(num_epochs-1): # don't print on all epochs
        # print statistics
        print('[%d] loss: %.8f' %
            (epoch, running_loss))

print('Finished Training')
```

Output:

```
[0] loss: 0.00629047
[1] loss: 0.00629047
[2] loss: 0.00629047
[4] loss: 0.00629047
[8] loss: 0.00629047
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is in your `getrotation` function. When creating a new tensor from the other tensors it is not back-probable anymore:

```py
def getrotation(self):
    sintheta = torch.sin(self.theta)
    costheta = torch.cos(self.theta)
    return torch.tensor([[costheta, -sintheta], [sintheta, costheta]], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.double)
```

So you need to find some other way to construct your return tensor.

Here is one suggestion that seems to work using `torch.cat`:

```py
def getrotation(self):
    sintheta = torch.sin(self.theta)
    costheta = torch.cos(self.theta)
    #return torch.tensor([[costheta, -sintheta], [sintheta, costheta]], requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.double)
    A = torch.cat([costheta.unsqueeze(0), -sintheta.unsqueeze(0)], dim=0)
    B = torch.cat([sintheta.unsqueeze(0), costheta.unsqueeze(0)], dim=0)
    return torch.cat([A.unsqueeze(0), B.unsqueeze(0)], dim=0).double()
```

After implementing this change the loss changes:

```py
[0] loss: 0.00765365
[1] loss: 0.00764726
[2] loss: 0.00764023
[4] loss: 0.00762607
[8] loss: 0.00759777
[16] loss: 0.00754148
[32] loss: 0.00742997
[64] loss: 0.00721117
[128] loss: 0.00679025
[256] loss: 0.00601233
[512] loss: 0.00469085
[999] loss: 0.00288501
Finished Training
```

I hope this helps!

---

**Edit:**
A simpler and prettier version by [@DanStowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563927/dan-stowell):

```py
def getrotation(self): 
    sintheta = torch.sin(net.theta).double().unsqueeze(0)
    costheta = torch.cos(net.theta).double().unsqueeze(0) 
    return torch.cat([costheta, -sintheta, sintheta, costheta]).reshape((2,2))
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I rewrote it mildly as:

```def getrotation(self):
        sintheta = torch.sin(net.theta).double().unsqueeze(0);
        costheta = torch.cos(net.theta).double().unsqueeze(0);
        return torch.cat([costheta, -sintheta, sintheta, costheta]).reshape((2,2))
```